# change working directory to current opened file

Tags: working-directory

Sometimes I use Command-T to browse files. When I find the file I needed, I would like to switch the current working directory to the opened file's directory. How can I do this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`:cd %:h`

Explain:
`:cd` change directory Vim command
`%` - full path to current file
`%:h` - full path to current file without filename itself.

See `:help expand` and `:help :cd` for more information

Comment: A better pointer: `:help cmdline-special`

Comment: @lcd047 yes! Agree! Very useful!

Comment: Additionally, the setting `autochdir` can be set in `.vimrc` to perform this action automatically.